# Best way to sync files across load balanced Windows instances on AWS?

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, rsync

I have just started exploring load balancing and have setup a couple of Windows instances running a .NET application.

Short of FTPing to each instance, what is the best way to sync my app across the X instances?

(Note, ive already created an AMI from my master instance, so this questions is more for incremental updates to each instance, rather than terminating them and starting the cluster again!)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Incremental updates can be done by making use of CloudFormation, cfn-init and cfn-hup.  I store a build number in the cloud metadata for the EC2 Launch Configuration, and when that changes, it downloads the next version directly onto the server via cfn-hup.

I've written part one on our blog - http://blog.kloud.com.au/2013/08/05/bootstrapping-on-aws.  But the key parts are

```
                "UserData" : { "Fn::Base64" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
                "<script>\n",
                    "powershell.exe add-windowsfeature web-webserver -includeallsubfeature -logpath $env:temp\\webserver_addrole.log \n",
                    "powershell.exe add-windowsfeature web-mgmt-tools -includeallsubfeature -logpath $env:temp\\mgmttools_addrole.log \n",
                    "cfn-init.exe -v -s ", {"Ref" : "AWS::StackId"}, " -r WebServerLaunchConfiguration --region ", {"Ref" : "AWS::Region"}, "\n",
                "</script>\n",
                "<powershell>\n",
                    "new-website -name", {"Ref" : "Name"}, " -port 80 -physicalpath c:\\inetpub\\", {"Ref" : "Name"}, " -ApplicationPool \".NET v4.5\" -force \n",
                    "remove-website -name \"Default Web Site\" \n",
                    "start-website -name ", {"Ref" : "Name"}, " \n",
                "</powershell>"
            ]]}
```

And in the meta data

```
"AWS::CloudFormation::Init" : {
                "config" : {
                    "files" : {
                        "c:\\cfn\\cfn-hup.conf" : {
                            "content" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
                                "[main]\n",
                                "stack=", { "Ref" : "AWS::StackId" }, "\n",
                                "region=", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, "\n",
                                "interval=5"
                            ]]}
                        },
                        "c:\\cfn\\hooks.d\\cfn-auto-reloader.conf" : {
                            "content": { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
                                "[cfn-auto-reloader-hook]\n",
                                "triggers=post.update\n",
                                "path=Resources.WebServerLaunchConfiguration.Metadata.AWS::CloudFormation::Init\n",
                                "action=cfn-init.exe -s ", { "Ref" : "AWS::StackId" }, " -r WebServerLaunchConfiguration --region ", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, "\n"
                            ]]}
                        }
                    },
                    "sources" : {
                        "c:\\inetpub\\wwwroot" : {"Fn::Join" : ["",[
                            "https://", {"Ref" : "ArtifactBucket"} ,".s3.amazonaws.com/", {"Ref":"Version"},"/artifact.zip"
                            ]]}
                    },
                    "packages" : {
                        "msi" : {
                            "urlrewrite" : "http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/7/D/67D80164-7DD0-48AF-86E3-DE7A182D6815/rewrite_2.0_rtw_x64.msi"
                        }
                    },
                    "services" : {
                        "windows" : {
                            "cfn-hup" : {
                                "enabled" : "true",
                                "ensureRunning" : "true",
                                "files" : ["c:\\cfn\\cfn-hup.conf", "c:\\cfn\\hooks.d\\cfn-auto-reloader.conf"]
                            }
                        }
                    },
```

So if you were to ignore the cfn-hup part (as I haven't written about that... yet) you can still do it by maintaining a launch configuration of x instances, and then just terminating them.  That would force a new launch.  But if you do go the cfn-hup path... and set the interval=1, then it will update all of them from the S3 bucket within a minute.

Comment: Wow, thats impressive and exactly what Im after. I think I need to increase my knowledge of Cloudformation (and AWS in general!). Can I ask where you learnt all the this from, as I find the documentation and general help behind this scripting very limited?

Comment: Mainly studying all variants of the sammple templates.  And a detailed reading of the documentation.  The AWS doco could do with some serious curation to pull it together, but when you do wade through it, it's actually quite comprehensive.  It's just not consolidated well.

Answer (score 0):

Terminating and having a boot script load and deploy the latest version of your application is one way of handling updates. Of course, you don't want to terminate all your instances at once, instead you want to do it in a rolling fashion.

If you want to limit your impact even further, you can launch a new infrastructure in parallel to the existing one, as the traffic swaps to the new application, you would terminate the existing instances.

Option two is to have a script poll a file on s3 looking for updates, when it does indicate an update, it would download the new application from s3 and deploy it.

Comment: I do like this idea. Are there any free scripts around which do this download of the files. Im not too handy on shell/windows scripts but this sounds like a good option. 

Referring to @Barak answer, I do like the drop box idea too but I guess that means maintaining drop box on each instance which I would maybe rather avoid.

In my case, an incremental roll out is not necessary. I actually need the opposite of this - all instances to be updated at once, so maybe the Cloudformation template/spin up new/spin down old instances is the better answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok to get dirty with some Chef you can probably use custom Opsworks servers to deploy new code across multiple instances. Otherwise as datasage suggested something like creating a Cloudformation template of your existing infrastructure with an AMI of the updated instance/code, deploy the new template and spin down your old infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

The previous suggestions are all solid options. Another option is to use a cloud storage provider like [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) or [Box](https://www.box.com/). You copy your new files to the 'shared folder' and they get updated to the server machines which should also have the cloud storage application correctly set up.

The main advantage of this approach is that it is very easy to set up, and for most applications the free or light versions of any cloud storage application will do the job.

There are disadvantages though. Mainly, doing a rolling upgrade can be trickier (not impossible, you need to manually trigger the sync with the cloud storage)

Regardless, don't use straight-up FTP - by default it is an insecure protocol - your files are not encrypted during transfer. Tunnel your traffic over a VPN or SSH, or use Powershell instead.